# Finding an explicit formula for a Hamiltonian vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, symplectic-geometry

I've been looking at this question: [Existence of vector field given a smooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673738/symplectic-manifold-m-unique-vector-field-x-f-on-m-so-that-dfy-omega)

That is: Given a symplectic manifold $M$ of dimension $2n$, with a symplectic form $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$, do we have for all smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$ a vector field $U_f$ on $M$ such that $df=i_{U_f}\omega$?

Alex M. gives an answer there using the musical isomorphisms, which assumes some previous knowledge with pseudo-Riemannian manifolds. I was wondering if one can give an explicit expression to the obtained vector field, as I am not so strong on the subject of Riemannian metrics, and cannot really decipher in terms of tangent vector what the expression should be.

I apologize if this is a trivial question, and would appreciate any help gaining insight as to how one can obtain an explicit formula for a Hamiltonian vector field?

Comment: The symplectic form can be seen as an invertible (non degenerate) type $(2,0)$ tensor $w_{ab}$. Or a linear form from $TM$ to $T*M$ . To obtain the vector field $U_f$, you simply compose the gradient of $f$ (which is a convector field) with the inverse of $w$ (which always exists, and can be seen as a linear form from    $T*M$ to $TM$ , or a type (0,2) tensor).

Comment: Perhaps I should have stated that I'm not that familiar with tensors, and have somewhat basic knowledge of differential forms as smooth anti-symmetric multi-linear forms. I am however familiar with bi-linear forms.

Comment: You treat the bilinear form $w$ as a matrix, the compute its inverse (the fact that the $w$ is non-degenerate is equivalent to its matrix being invertible). Then you apply this inverse matrix to the gradient of $f$. The gradient of is a 1-form field, and the inverse matrix $w^{-1}$ will transform it to a vector field (instead of taking vectors to $1$-forms, as $w$ does, it will take $1$-forms to vectors.)

Comment: Would you mind writing your comment as an answer? Or I could write my attempt at an answer and you'll tell me whether it is correct. Anyway I think your comments answered my question.

Comment: You can write the answer. It'd help me to understand how the answer is supposed to look like, ie. what notations are used.

Comment: I've added an attempt at an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt at an answer using the help given by user3257842:

Let $\{ e_1(p),....,e_{2n}(p) \}$ be a basis for $T_p(M)$, orthonormal with respect to the Riemannian metric $\rho$. Define the representing matrix of $\omega_p$ to be $B(p)\in \mathbb{R}_{2n \times 2n}$, by:  $ B_{i,j}(p):= \omega_p \Big( e_i, e_j \Big) $

We know that for two tangent vectors $\eta_{(1)}$ and $\eta_{(2)}$ we have:

$ \omega(\eta_{(1)},\eta_{(2)}) = \eta_{(1)}^t \cdot B(p)\cdot \eta_{(2)}  $, 
 with coordinate vectors with respect to the above orthonormal basis.

For all $\eta\in T_p(M)$ we have that:
   $ dH_p(\eta)= \rho( \nabla H(p), \eta ) $

And by our choice of basis, we have that:
   $ dH_p(\eta)= \Big( \nabla H(p) \Big) ^t \cdot \eta $, 
   with the coordinate vectors with respect to our orthonormal basis.

Let us define $X_h(p)$ by:
   $ X_H(p):=\Big( \nabla H(p) \Big) ^t\cdot \Big( B(p) \Big)^{-1} $

By this definition, we can see that:

$ \Big( X_H\Big)^t B(p)= \Big( \nabla H(p) \Big) ^t\cdot \Big( B(p) \Big)^{-1} \cdot B(p)=\Big( \nabla H(p) \Big)^t $

And therefore:

$ \omega(X_H(p), \eta)= dH(\eta) \quad \text{for all} \quad \eta \in T_p(M) $

This will be our Hamiltonian vector field. 
   Let us notice, that since $\omega$ is invertible and smooth, if we denote it's inverse $\omega^{-1}$, then it is also smooth. i.e, the entries of $\Big( B(p) \Big)^{-1}$ are also smooth as a function of $p$. And we obtain that $X_H$ is a result of a composition of smooth maps, and is therefore smooth.

Comment: Looks good to me. You should look into Ricci-calculus/ [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_field). It makes these things easier to express. You'd basically have two types of "building blocks" : vectors $V^{a}, a\in \{1..n\}$, that transform under change of coordinate by composing with the jacobian of the coordinate function, co-vectors $C_{a}, a\in \{1..n\}$ that transform under change of coordinate by composing with the inverse of the jacobian of the coordinate function, and mixed objects that are made by sums of tensor products of the basic objects.

Comment: Eg: the wedge product of two $1$-forms can be defined as: $v_{a} \wedge k_{b} = v_{a}k_{b} - v_{b}k_{a}$. You can see that the result is an asymmetric matrix by swapping the $a$ and $b$ indices around (indices act as labels) . Our $2$-form $\omega$ is written as $\omega_{ab}$, and the equation $df(Y)= \omega(X_f, Y)$ becomes $\forall Y, f_{,a}Y^{a} =   \omega_{cd} {X_f}^{c} Y^{d}$ . As $d$ is a ["dummy index"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation#Introduction) (only servers to link $w$ to $Y$, is not free), we can swap it with $a$, then simplify $Y^{a}$ from the equation.

Comment: We get $\forall Y, f_{,a}Y^{a} =   \omega_{ca} {X_f}^{c} Y^{a}$, and then we simplify $Y^{a}$, to obtain $f_{,a} = \omega_{ca}{X_f}^{c}$ . From here it's obvious we must compose $f_{,a}$ with an inverse of  $\omega_{ca}$ to get ${X_f}^{c}$ . It's unfortunate that the $f$ in $X_f$ looks like an index, even tough it isn't. We obtain $f_{,a} (\omega^{-1})^{ca} ={X_f}^{c} $.